# How to remove vowels from a string, and store result in another string

Tags: c++, ascii

I want to program a console application to remove vowels from a string, storing the result (string without vowels) in another string.

How should I do it??

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
string a,b;
int s=0,r,t;
cin>>a;
int k=a.size();
for(int y=0;y<k;y++){
        if(a[y]==65||a[y]==97||a[y]==69||a[y]==101||a[y]==73||a[y]==105||a[y]==79||a[y]==111||a[y]==85||a[y]==117||a[y]==89||a[y]==121){
        }
        else{
            b[s]=a[y];



            s++;

        }



}
    cout<<b;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe *exactly* what you mean by "doesn't work". Also, please format your code to make it readable. You can paste your code [here](http://format.krzaq.cc/) and just click format.

Comment: and never use magic numbers like `a[y]==65`. Use `a[y] == 'A'` instead

Comment: I think this is better:

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
string a,b;
int s=0,r,t;
cin>>a;
int k=a.size();
for(int y=0;y<k;y++){
        if(a[y]==65||a[y]==97||a[y]==69||a[y]==101||a[y]==73||a[y]==105||a[y]==79||a[y]==111||a[y]==85||a[y]==117||a[y]==89||a[y]==121){
        }
        else{
            b[s]=a[y];



            s++;

        }



}
    cout<<b;


    return 0;
}

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things I want to highlight

> Try to avoid comparisons with ASCII a[y]==97 instead you can use a[y]=='a'

> Always include header #include < string > while dealing with string functions and output

> No need to do like this it's hard to read and understand you can create an array/Vector of characters like

```
std::vector<char> vowels{'A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u'}
```

> Use getline() instead of cin         \\ You can visit [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

> You can do a case insensitive comparison if it's the need

This is my version of code

```
int main(){
string a,b;
std::vector<char> vowels{'A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u'};
getline(cin,a);
for(auto ch:a){
        if(find(vowels.begin(),vowels.end(),ch)!=vowels.end()){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            b+=a
        }
}
    cout<<b;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) might help also, (or even [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove))